# How to open a terminal on WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

How do I get WebStorm to open a terminal?

When I try to do it I get an Exception:

```
"java.io.IOEXception:couldn't create PTY"
```

git also has the same problem on my computer.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Go to `File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal` and change Shell path based on the the installed git version.

for 64bit:
`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i`

for 32bit:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i`

Don't forget the quotes around the command.

Comment: +1.  For me it was the opposite however, changed from the x86 version to 64-bit version and then it worked

Comment: This used to work for me, but today I had to remove the -login -i and just have ...\sh.exe (seems to do a proper login anyway). Might be the latest Idea EAP update

Comment: same for me, if I go back to non-eap phpstorm it works, must be this eap build

Comment: For eap 145.969  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136139, just enclose path with quotes "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i

Comment: It used to be the same config. for me as well -
[path to git]\bash.exe -i

But after IntelliJ's security update I've done, it stopped working
(even what @john-doe had suggested didn't help)

Then I've tried inserting just the path and it's working.

Comment: FWIW, this same general fix worked for IntelliJ on Windows 10, except that I had to use `"C:\Users\troy.gizzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i`. (The full hard-coded path was required; it did not work with `%UserProfile%`.)

Answer (score 26):

After the latest update the path needs to be in **enclosed in quotes**:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i
```

Comment: I am using 213.1.3. file path within double quote  worked for me. :)

Comment: That's it! For some reason, it was working fine without the quotes before but after some update, it stopped and I couldn't figure out why it's not working anymore. In my case it was in *PyCharm*.

Answer (score 15):

If you have the 64bit version of Git use

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i
```

If you have the 32bit version use

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i
```

If you have installed ubuntu for windows 10 you can use

```
bash.exe
```

Comment: bash.exe uses the current start directory.

Answer (score 8):

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /k "D:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\init.bat
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: oh i just use cmder... i think it is much better in Windows

Comment: For me, this worked     "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /K C:\Users\Venv1\Scripts\activate.bat     
Notice the difference in quote placement

Comment: In pycharm 4 this worked fine, but in pycharm 2016.3.2 I had to switch the quotes like in Sharad's comment!

Comment: yes. in some version it dosent work very well, i have found it after upgrading my Webstrom. sry for replying late, i am busy working on my Master’s thesis.

Answer (score 5):

Go To View --> Tool Windows --> Terminal (or) Just Alt + F12.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Windows Command Prompt you will need to add double quotes, so `cmd.exe` becomes `"cmd.exe"`.

Comment: really. I finally made cmder work with `"cmd.exe" /k ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat""`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For version `phpstorm 2017` (windows 10), the below settings work!
[image]

change the `Path` to your project path

change `user_name_win` to your win username

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017 `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"` in the shell path works perfectly on x64.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 users, we now have Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) so go to:

File > Settings > Tools > Terminal and put in shell path:

`"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C "bash"`

Note that you need to enable [developer mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development), and then WSL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu, change shell path from `File->Setting->Terminal->Shell` path:

```
/bin/bash --login
```

Then restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 you may prefer use terminal from Windows Subsystem for Linux.
For this need put path to bash.exe.

In my case it was:

```
c:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-lxss-bash_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.0_none_50af37c8f560d163\bash.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that I had the "Start directory" field of the Tools > Terminal settings page set to a path which didn't exist on my drive.  It's too bad the error message is not more specific when this kind of mistake is made.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error with Cmder as my custom terminal. I ran PhpStorm 2018.2 as admin. That fixed the issue for me. No double quotes needed.