# Startup file for terminal in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cmd

Is there a way to setup a startup file for terminal in Android Studio? (This file will be automatically executed when terminal starts.)

Tried (in Windows) to specify Shell Path (in Settings/Tools/Terminal)  as

```
cmd -K startup.bat
```

with `startup.bat` residing in Start Directory. Got error message:

```
java.IO.IOException: Couldn't create PTY
```

Comment: What do you mean by "for terminal in Android Studio"? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Could you show your script? Is it starting something needing a PTY? Seen this, I assume? https://superuser.com/a/144349/475508 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/42890952/2308683

Comment: cricket_007: When I open Terminal window in Android Studio this file should run automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090800/how-to-open-a-terminal-on-webstorm/42890952#42890952) I figured out the problem.

The correct syntax for `Shell path` in `Settings/Tools/Terminal` is

```
"cmd.exe" /k startup.bat
```

I looks rather weird, but cmd.exe must be in double quotes, otherwise it won't be accepted.

Comment: This works on new Android Studio version 3.3.2. Thanks